# Batch file has an error that when called from a Powershell script does not allow the batch file to finish

Tags: powershell

In the script below I am calling a batch file to break mirroring between some dbs.  The batch file has a user prompt to start the script but the PS script races right past it.  When I call the batch file directly from the powershell console it works fine.  How can I keep the script from move past the invoke command block with until the batch file is complete?

```
    $session = New-PSSession -computerName xssqlk02 -credential $cred

    Invoke-Command -Session $session -Scriptblock {c:\MSSQL\DBMaintenance\Mirroring\SERVER_Remove_Mirroring.bat xssqlk02 ossqlk02}

    Remove-PSSession $session
```

edit: I trimmed up just the part of the code that I am having problems with.  When this is run from a ps script I just noticed (it's been a long day....) I am getting the following error and it runs through the user prompt at that point.

PS C:\Users\dans> C:\Tools\Scripts\test5.ps1
A subdirectory or file c:\MSSQL\DBMaintenance\Mirroring\Common already exists.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (A subdirectory ...already exists.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Invalid drive specification
Remove Mirroring for RCM databases between xssqlk02 and ossqlk02: Continue? y/n 0 File(s) copied

Here is what the output is when I just run the batchfile directly from the PS console on the local machine.
PS C:\Documents and Settings\DanS> c:\MSSQL\DBMaintenance\Mirroring\SERVER_Remove_Mirroring.bat xssqlk02 ossqlk02
Remove Mirroring for RCM databases between xssqlk02 and ossqlk02: Continue? y/n y

**A subdirectory or file c:\MSSQL\DBMaintenance\Mirroring\Common already exists.**

\OPFLSK02\SQLBackupsForTape\DBMaintenance\Mirroring\Common\DB_Create_Snapshots.bat
\OPFLSK02\SQLBackupsForTape\DBMaintenance\Mirroring\Common\DB_Force_Mirror_To_Principal.bat
.......
18 File(s) copied

The error occurs because the batch file does not have a check to see if the directory already exists.  How do I handle this is from the invoke command block to allow the script to continue?   For the moment I am not able to change the batch file itself.

Comment: after working with the owner of the bat file we resolved serveral issues and eventually we were able to take this out of the remote context which was causing the double hop problem.  I was then able to take part of George's code: Start-Process -FilePath "C:\MSSQL\DBMaintenance\Mirroring\SERVER_Remove_Mirroring.bat" -ArgumentList "xssqlk02", "ossqlk02" -Wait and utilized that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Alexey's solution doesn't work, you can try this one:

```
$job = Invoke-Command -Session $session -Scriptblock { Start-Process -FilePath "C:\MSSQL\DBMaintenance\Mirroring\SERVER_Remove_Mirroring.bat" -ArgumentList "xssqlk02", "ossqlk02" -Wait } -AsJob
$job | Wait-Job
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try so

Invoke-Command -Session $session -Scriptblock {**start** c:\MSSQL\DBMaintenance\Mirroring\SERVER_Remove_Mirroring.bat xssqlk02 ossqlk02 **-wait**}

The idea is that the cmdlet will wait until you finish the bat file.

Comment: this did not actually work I get the following error when I and the start and -wait items:  A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'ossqlk02'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Comment: Try changing it to this: `Invoke-Command -Session $session -Scriptblock { Start-Process -FilePath "C:\MSSQL\DBMaintenance\Mirroring\SERVER_Remove_Mirroring.bat" -ArgumentList "xssqlk02", "ossqlk02" -Wait }` although I'm not 100% sure that it will work.

Comment: that actually just caused the script to start and just sit there with no prompt or action what so ever.  I just noticed something else so I am going to edit the question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

"Invalid drive specification Remove Mirroring for RCM databases between xssqlk02 and ossqlk02:"

it may indicate that $session dont have access to ossqlk02.
Try appoint yourself an admin on all computers and run script under admin. If it does not help, you can to use utility - PsExec [link PsExec support](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

Comment: I am pretty confident that it is not a permission issue since I am an admin on the box.  Also if you notice the error detials the problem is that the batch file I am calling is trying to create a directory that already exists.  The is somethig about the error when it is being run as part of a remote process that is causing it to run over the user prompt and the actualy running of the batch file.